# Android icons within strings.xml

Tags: android, android-resources

How I can change some icons which are declared in strings.xml

```
<resources>
   ...
    <string name="icon_info">&#xf129;</string>
    <string name="icon_heart">&#xf004;</string>
   ....
```

and after I use them in some source files in java

```
Button txt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.infotxt); 
Button txt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.hearttxt); 

Typeface webfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
txt.setText(" " + getString(R.string.icon_info) + " ...");
txt.setTypeface(webfont);
txt1.setText(" " + getString(R.string.icon_heart) + " ...");
txt1.setTypeface(webfont);
```

I would like to change these icons to other icons I have  on my computer.

Comment: You want to replace them by some other characters of another icon font or by some image.

Comment: @Henry by some png image/icon

Comment: *"other icons I have on my computer"* - They need to be on the android device, not your computer. *"Change the icons"* - those xml files are read-only

Comment: Some more work then. I guess `txt` and `txt1` point to TextView instances? Then you may need to adapt your layout.

Comment: @cricket_007 Actually I will have them in the asset folder \

Comment: @Henry Button txt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.infotxt);
        Button txt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.hearttxt);

Answer (score 1):

```
  <string name="icon_info">&#xf129;</string>
  <string name="icon_heart">&#xf004;</string>
```

they are fonts, not real images icon!!!!
you can do :
1. convert your icons to font and use it as same as above, look at [this](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-turn-your-icons-into-a-web-font/) article 
also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959751/how-to-use-font-awesome-icon-in-android-application?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is usefull.
2. put your image file in drawable or assets and use it as a normal image file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the first solution it's complicated

Comment: Is there any other ready fonts? maybe I can find similar icons

Comment: yes, google font icon...
but I think it's better and easier to use materials icons. 
https://materialdesignicons.com/
and 
https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

Comment: How to use them? Can you help me by changing the code? partial

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689130/create-icon-button-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: choose your icon from https://materialdesignicons.com/ 
then select view vector drawable and save it as xml. put it in drawable folder and use it. an other way is using ImageButton instead of button